# How many (base 10) digits does $10000!$ have?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many (base 10) digits does $10000!$ have?

This question just came out of the blue in our Combinatorics class.  Our professor was talking about Stirling approximation and I assume this has to do with it but I can't seem to make the connection.

Comment: Ah, I was going to say "Stirling's formula", but I don't have to!

Comment: Stirling's approximation.

Comment: If you have some big number and you want to know how many digits it has, what is the operation you apply to that number to get an answer?

Comment: You can check your answer at http://oeis.org/A034886/b034886.txt

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The digits $D$ of a number $n$ is given by
$$D = \lfloor \log_{10}n \rfloor +1.$$

The floor function $\lfloor \cdot\rfloor$ rounds the inner expression to the next smaller or equal integer. In addition to this use Stirling's approximation.

Comment: I think I got it thanks!

Comment: Or just use $\lceil x \rceil$ instead of $\lfloor x \rfloor$.

Comment: @SharkyKesa: Thx for the edit, I didn't know how to use the floor function notation :).